# How to fix <iv=None> in numba?

Tags: python, numba

I have a dict that takes a tuple of ints as keys and a numpy array as values. Here is a MWE:

```
import numba as nb
import numpy as np
@nb.njit
def make_dict():
    d = {}
    A = (np.ones(10))
    d[(1, 2, 3)] = A
    return d
B = make_dict()
print(repr(B))
```

If I then look at B I get

```
DictType[UniTuple(int64 x 3),array(float64, 1d, C)]<iv=None>({(1, 2, 3): [1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1. 1.]})
```

I think <iv=None> means that the type is unspecified which I am assuming means it won't be optimally compiled. How can I fix this?

Comment: I compile the script successfully. Also `print(B[(1, 2, 3)])` works afterwards. Using `numba==0.57.1`

Comment: @AndrejKesely yes it runs but when you do "B" in ipython do you see the iv=None? I am just worried about whether a typing problem is stopping it from being compiled optimally.

Comment: Yes, when I do `print(repr(B))` I see `iv=None`

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thanks. I added that to the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Why do you think it won't be optimally compiled? `iv=` means Initial Value.

Comment: @AndrejKesely I didn't know that. What had an initial value of None though?

Comment: When you use `njit`, Numba compiles the code to a native function. It cannot operate on objects (except in some special cases : when the user explicitly request that using the temporary objmode). If you get no warning, then there is no issue with objects. Objects are possible in the `jit` mode (`nopython=False`), but this mode is quite useless IMHO.

Comment: `iv=None` is maybe because `{}` is not typed. Numba needs to unify it with the type extract from the line `d[(1, 2, 3)]`. Otherwise, the dict type would have been impossible to deduce you would have got a compilation error with `njit`. You can create the dict directly with the right type explicitly (though this is cumbersome). See the functions in `typed` and `types`.